# Express: abstracting away middleware for app.use

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, middleware

I want to go from this code in my index.js

```
app.use(require('sass-middleware').middleware({
  src: path.resolve(__dirname, '../'),
  dest: path.resolve(__dirname, '../public')
}));
app.use(require('browserify-dev-middleware')({
  src: path.resolve(__dirname, '../'),
  transforms: [require('jadeify')]
}));
```

to this:

```
app.use(require('asset-pipeline-dev-middelware'));
```

but I just don't know how to make the function that is passed in to app.use be a proxy for the other two middleware functions.

Something like this fills wrong, or is it fine?

```
require('asset-pipeline-dev-middelware')(app);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can group the middlewares like this:

```
//asset-pipeline-dev-middelware.js
var middleware1 = require('first-middleware')
var middleware2 = require('second-middleware')

function(req, res, next){
    middleware1(req, res, function(err){
        if(err) return next(err);
        middleware2(req, res, next)
    })
}
```

then use it in app just like you mentioned:

```
app.use(require('asset-pipeline-dev-middelware'));
```

Comment: i've found something interesting about this, see my answer below

Answer (score 2):

this also works because `app.use` can handle arrays

```
// asset-pipeline-dev-middelware.js
var middleware1 = require('first-middleware')
var middleware2 = require('second-middleware')

module.export = [middleware1, middleware2];

// index.js
app.use(require('asset-pipeline-dev-middelware'));
```

Comment: Interesting.. Didn't know it could handle array of middlewares.